# How to encrypt client-side subversion password on a command-line only Ubuntu machine

Tags: svn, encryption

Is there a way to encrypt client-side svn user passwords on a terminal-only Ubuntu machine? (ie. the subversion server is accessible through https).

I've got a hosted svn repository accessible over `https`. I've also got a `VPS` running some services. I'm backing up data on the VPS on a regular basis (using `cron`). This backup is one small gzipped file which changes rarely, I always overwrite the old file with the newest version, so there is always only one file. I would like to store this file in the svn repository and do a commit each time a new backup has been produced. I would like to do this with cron as well, but wouldn't like to store my svn-account's password unencrypted on the VPS in any way. I know there are some easy gnome and KDE solutions, but I haven't got gui. Are there any command-line password-managers which work well with subversion?

Any hints?

Comment: You could use svn+ssh and use an ssh key for authentication but then the ssh key is just as vulnerable as the password.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I think I have no svn+ssh access to my repository, just https. Apart from that, AFAIK, I would have to be able to generate a ssh key on the server side to do that, which I cannot.

Answer (score 2):

What would the point of storing the crypted password be? Presumably you'd need to decrypt the key within the cron script, which means you'd have to store the decryption key. So instead of storing a plaintext password, you're storing a crypted password and the key to decrypt it.

In real world terms, you'll have an unbreakable bank vault with the access code on a post-it next to the door's keypad.

Comment: I rather thought it would be possible to generate an RSA key (or alike) and store just the public key in some folder, for example.

Comment: True, but then you've got the public key right there, and anyone can grab it and get at your repository. You can crypt the key, but that puts you right back in the same boat - you'd have to store the decryption key somewhere where the script can get at it.

Comment: True, someone could grab the public key and access my data. But anyway, I feel more comfortable with the idea of a public key being stolen than my password being seen. I guess no one likes their passwords being revealed, that's one of the main reasons I would like to encrypt it as the VPS is shared. But, of course, thanks for your opinion and help.